# Remotely registering/unregistering a BroadcatReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, registering

i was wondering whether there is a way for a BroadcastReceiver contained in an activity/service, to be remotely registered/unregistered in code.

Is it feasible at all or should i implement an intermediate external BroadcastReceiver to do the job?

Comment: The job is: Having an external, intermediate, "stand-alone" proximity receiver for accepting the proximity alerts and when it detects something it will inform a service internal BroadcastReceiver. In that way, i might be able to turn on/off the external BroadcasteReceiver when i want to open/close my Application's "ears", unless if there is a way to do the same, having only the service internal receiver...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using some specialized hardware.  If you have control over its design, you might be able to use bluetooth to accomplish what you're looking for.  If you make your external sensor behave as a bluetooth device with avrcp, you can have it send something like the pause/play key and then have your app your app bind to the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent.  Your activity would be invoked automatically by the OS whenever it receives the event, just be sure that your receiver is of a higher priority than the built in media player, and consume the event by returning true, or the built in player will start.  Kind of a kludge I suppose, but I think this would accomplish what you're looking for.

Or I'm off the mark and misunderstand your question entirely.